# Show $K$ is a ring using matrix addition and multiplication rules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Let $K$ be the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices of form 
$\begin{pmatrix}
   a & b \\
    b& a
\end{pmatrix}$ and let $a ,b \in \mathcal{Z}$. I know I need to use addition and multiplication as the binary operations of the ring but I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: Do you know the ring axioms?

Comment: I know a ring is a set with two binary operations.  For addition R is an abelian group and multiplication is associative and distributive.

Comment: Write out three arbitrary matrices in your set K. Show that they satisfy commutativity and associativity (additive), that there exists an additive inverse and identity. Then show that they satisfy left and right distributivity as well as associativity (multiplicative).

Comment: Can you show work for what you have done thus far. Then I can be able to assist you further.

Comment: $\begin{matrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{matrix}$ + $\begin{matrix} (a& b\\b&a) \end{matrix}$ = $\begin{matrix} (2a& 2b\\ 2b&2a) \end{matrix}$ and $\begin{matrix} (a& b\\ b&a) \end{matrix} * \begin{matrix} (a& b\\ b&a) \end{matrix}$ = $ \begin{matrix} (a^2b^2& a^2b^2\\a^2b^2&a^2b^2) \end{matrix}$